# Want to compare string in two columns and bring equal values in same row in python pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare two columns where values in both columns are not sorted so, compare them so that similar values in both the columns will be in a same row.

input_data:

```
A    B
1a    nan
2b    3c
3c    2b
4d    1a
```

Expected_output:

```
A    B
1a    1a
2b    2b
3c    3c
4d    nan
```

Comment: Do you only have two columns?

Answer (score 2):

If there are only two columns to line up, then this turns out to be a `merge` problem - perform a LEFT OUTER JOIN on A and B to line up equal values, filling NaNs where there are no matches:

```
df[['A']].merge(df[['B']], how='left', left_on='A', right_on='B')

   A    B
0  1    1
1  2    2
2  3    3
3  4  NaN
```

You can also use `pd.merge` which supports merging Series:

```
pd.merge(df['A'], df['B'], left_on='A', right_on='B', how='left')

   A    B
0  1    1
1  2    2
2  3    3
3  4  NaN
```

Comment: sorry for not defining question correctly...but yes sorting will not solve the problem as it should compare strings in both columns...I have edited the question now

Comment: @GaneshKharad this answer will still work, can you check it? It uses merge, not sort.